# Algebraic proof regarding falling factorials

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

> Let $n$ and $k$ be positive integers with $n \ge k$.
> Give an algebraic proof that $$(n)_k = (n-1)_k + k\cdot(n-1)_{k-1},$$ where $(n)_k$ is a falling factorial: $(n)_k$ = $(n)(n-1)(n-2)\ldots(n-k+1)$.

I started by turning LHS into

$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} = \frac{((n+k)-k)!}{(n-k)!}$$

I tried doing this after:

$$ = \frac{(((n+k)-k)(n-1))!}{(n-k)!}$$

but I really have no idea where else to proceed. I'm not sure how I can split it up or move past this.
Does anyone think they can point me in the right path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**General hint**:

When proving $a=b$, it is not always the easiest to start with $a$ and convert it into $b$. There are several other options that can be easier to do, including, but not limited to:

- Proving that $a-b=0$
- Proving that $|a-b|=0$
- Proving that $(a-b)^2=0$
- Proving that $a=c$ and that $b=c$.
- Proving that $a\leq b$ and $b\leq a$

---

You seem to be stuck because you only tried the head-on way of taking $a$ and converting it into $b$. Now, this is **possible***, but it is by no means the easiest way. In fact, the easiest way in this case would be to modify *both* sides of the equation, and show they both equal some other expression.

In particular, the same way you converted the LHS, you can also convert the RHS into

$$\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1-k)!} + k\cdot\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1-(k-1))!} $$

Now, use the fact that $(n-1-(k-1))! = (n-k)! = (n-k)\cdot (n-1-k)!$

and sum up the two fractions.

---

* It is possible, because:

> $$\begin{align} (n)_k &= \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\\ &= \frac{n! - k\cdot(n-1)! + k\cdot (n-1)! }{(n-k)!}\\ &=\frac{[n\cdot(n-1)! - k\cdot(n-1)!] + k\cdot(n-1)!}{(n-k)!}\\ &=\frac{n\cdot(n-1)! - k\cdot(n-1)!}{(n-k)!} + k\cdot\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!}\\ &=\frac{(n-1)! \cdot (n-k)}{(n-k)!} + k\cdot\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k-1+1)!}\\ &=\frac{(n-1)!\cdot (n-k)}{(n-k-1)!\cdot(n-k)} + k\cdot \frac{(n-1)!}{((n-1)-(k-1))!}\\ &=\frac{(n-1)!}{((n-1)-k)!} + k\cdot \frac{(n-1)!}{((n-1)-(k-1))!}\\ &=(n-1)_k + k\cdot (n-1)_{k-1}\end{align}$$

Comment: The very last line of the "it is possible" proof should have $(n - 1)_k$ not $(n)_k$ I think

Comment: @TavianBarnes Yup. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to how exponents obey the rule $n^k=n\cdot n^{k-1}$, falling factorials obey the rules
$$
(n)_k=n\cdot (n-1)_{k-1},\qquad (n)_k=(n-k+1)\cdot (n)_{k-1}
$$
which hollow by pulling out either the first or last factor of $(n)_k$. Using these,
$$
\begin{align}
(n)_k
&=n\cdot (n-1)_{k-1}
\\&=[(n-k)+k](n-1)_{k-1}
\\&=(n-k)\cdot (n-1)_{k-1} +k\cdot(n-1)_{k-1}
\\&=(n-1)_k+k\cdot (n-1)_{k-1} 
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$(n)_k-(n-1)_k=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}-\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k-1)!}=\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k-1)!}(\frac{n}{n-k}-1)=\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k-1)!}\times \frac{k}{n-k}=\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!}\times k=k(n-1)_{k-1}$